# Exercise 7.8 in Villani's Topics in Optimal Transportation (disintegration of measure)

Tags: real-analysis, probability-theory, measure-theory, optimal-transport

Consider a probability measure on the product of Polish spaces $X \times Y$. The disintegration of measure theorem allows one to write probability measures on $X \times Y$ as an average of probability measures on $\{x\} \times Y$ for $x \in X$. In particular, if $\mu$ is the marginal of $\pi$ on $X$ then there exists a measurable map $\pi_x$ from $X$ to probability measure on Y such that
$$
\pi = \int_{X}{(\delta_x \otimes \pi_x)}{\; \text{d}\,\mu(x)}. 
$$

*The exercise* (7.8, page 210) asks for the statement of disintegration of measure when all the measures in consideration are absolutely continuous with respect to a fixed reference measure, for instance the Lebesgue measure. I will further add the requirement that they have a continuous density. In particular what is the form of $\pi_x$?

**My attempt**

Write $\lambda_U$ the Lebesgue measure on $U$ and suppose that $\pi$ (resp. $\mu$) is absolutely continuous w.r.t. the Lebesgue measure with continuous density $w_\pi: X\times Y \rightarrow \mathbb R_+$ (resp. $w_\mu:X \rightarrow \mathbb R_+$). Then we have that the measurable map from $X$ to $P(Y)$ has the following form:
$$
\begin{aligned}
    & X \rightarrow P(Y)\\
    & x \mapsto  \pi_x = w^\text{des}(x,-)\; \text{d}\, \lambda_Y
    \end{aligned}
$$
where
$$
    w^\text{des}(x,-):\begin{aligned}
    & Y \rightarrow \mathbb R_+ \\
    & y \mapsto \begin{cases}
                    \frac{w_\pi(x,y)}{w_\mu(x)}& & \text{ if } w_\mu(x) \neq 0 \\
                    0 & &\text{ otherwise}
                \end{cases}
\end{aligned}
$$

*I am failing to see whether $w^\text{des}$ is indeed still continuous (or at least $L^1$) so that $\pi_x$ is also absolutely continuous w.r.t. the Lebesgue measure (which I assume is true). Having continuity preserved is also very desirable for me.*

EDIT : there was a typo in the expression of $w^\text{des}$ (I had written $w_\mu(y)$ instead of $w_\mu(x)$). This makes de facto the map continuous so I think it closes the question.

Comment: Should it be $w_{\mu}(x)$ instead of $w_{\mu}(y)$?  $\mu$ lives on $X$, no?

Comment: (Also, if you haven't done so before, it would broaden your perspective to compare how this is done in elementary probability textbooks.  You would be looking for conditional probability for "continuous random variables.")

Comment: @PeterMorfe thanks a lot for spotting the typo. Yes indeed. That makes de facto the map continuous so I guess that solves the issue I had since I believe the derivation is correct otherwise.

Comment: Also no, I haven't done so. I just had a look at Vorob'ev theorem before seeing that textbook from Villani. I'll try to have a look at that then.

Comment: This is nothing but the usual Probability 101 formula for conditional densities, except that you ay be working now on Polish spaces. Suppose $(X,\mathscr{B}(X),\lambda_X)$ and $(Y,\mathscr{B}(Y),\lambda_Y)$ are measure Polish spaces equipped with the Borel $\sigma$-algebras, and $\lambda_X$ and $\lambda_Y$ $\sigma$-finite measures on $X$ and $Y$ espectiv ely. Assume that $\pi$ is a probability measure on the product space $(X\times Y, \mathscr{B}(X)\otimes\mathscr{B}(Y))$ and that $\pi\ll \lambda_X\otimes\lambda_Y$, that is
$$
\pi(dx,dy)=f(x,y)\,\lambda_X(dx)\otimes\lambda_Y(dy)
$$

Comment: Several applications of Fubini's theorem gives that, for any $A\in\mathscr{B}(X)$ and $B\in\mathscr{B}(Y)$
$$\begin{align}
\pi(A\times B)&=\int_{X\times Y}\mathbb{1}_{A}(x)\mathbb{1}_B(y) f(x,y)\,\lambda_X(dx)\otimes\lambda_Y(dy)\\
&=\int_X\mathbb{1}_A(x)\left( \frac{1}{m(x)}\int_Y\mathbb{1}_B(y)f(x,y)\,\lambda_Y(dy)\right)\,m(x)\,\lambda_Y(dx)
\end{align}$$
where 
$$ m(x)=\int_Yf(x,y)\lambda_Y(dy)$$
The function $m(x)$ is the Radon-Nikodym derivative of the marginal of $\pi$ on $X$ with respect to $\lambda_X$. That is
$$ \pi(A\times Y)=\int_X\mathbb{1}_A(x)\,m(x)\,\lambda_X(dx)$$

Comment: It's maybe more clear when it's written like that indeed.
Second line of $\pi(A\times B)$ computation, it should be $\lambda_X$ instead of $\lambda_Y$.
And I guess you have the convention that $\frac 1 {m(x)} \int_Y \mathbb 1_B(y) f(x,y) \lambda_Y(dy) = 0 $ whenever $m(x) = 0$. 

In fact, I am trying to use the gluing lemma presented in Villani's work and originally in Vorob've's paper to see if I preserve absolute continuity and continuous density whenever I glue together two measures with these properties.

Comment: Gluing measures consists in taking the joint measure with the common marginal and the conditional probability densities. And with the above conditions the conditional probability can be seen as the density $ \frac{f(x,y)}{m(x)}$. Gluing together $\pi_{X,Y}$ with density $f_{XY}$ and $\pi_{Y,Z}$ with density $f_{YZ}$ with common marginal on $Y$ with density $m_Y$ thus yields the density $\frac{f_{XY}}{m_Y} m_Y \frac{f_{YZ}}{m_Y}$ which is indeed continuous.